# Connecting Seekbar with Hardware buttons on device

Tags: android, button, hardware, seekbar

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;



public class pushke extends Activity {


    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 
      MediaPlayer mp;
      MediaPlayer mp2;
      MediaPlayer mp3;
      MediaPlayer mp4;
      MediaPlayer mp5;
      MediaPlayer mp6;
      SeekBar seekGuns;
      RelativeLayout rguns;


     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            setContentView(R.layout.guns);
            initControls();
           rguns=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rguns);



mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (mp2.isPlaying()){
            mp2.pause();
            mp2.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp3.isPlaying()){
            mp3.pause();
            mp3.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp4.isPlaying()){
            mp4.pause();
            mp4.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp5.isPlaying()){
            mp5.pause();
            mp5.seekTo(0);

        }
        if (mp6.isPlaying()){
            mp6.pause();
            mp6.seekTo(0);

        }
        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            mp.start();
        }

    }
});
} 
     private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekGuns);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
   { 
          int index = seekGuns.getProgress(); 
          seekGuns.setProgress(index + 1); 
          return true; 
   } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
          int index = seekGuns.getProgress(); 
          seekGuns.setProgress(index - 1); 
          return true; 
   }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
```

I am trying to connect hardware buttons to my seekbar so when I click on volume buttons, seekbar which is used for volume, increase-decrease depending on which button I pressed.
I got this code which is supposed to be working, but I have no idea why it's not working in my case, everytime I launch my app on phone as emulator, and use hardware volume button app crashes.
I get this in LoGcat but Ican't figure out how to fix it or where is the problem because eclipse is not showing me any errors.
Here is my logcat: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBNd3.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have declared two ***Seekbar*** variables.

```
 private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
 SeekBar seekGuns;
```

and in your ***onKeyDown*** method you are using ***seekGuns*** named variable which is not initialized.

So you have two option.

1) Initialize means find the id for ***seekguns*** variable.

2) Use ***volumeSeekbar*** instead of ***seekguns*** in ***onKeyDown*** method.